# Airline ignoring Montreal Convention

Tags: canada, consumer-protection, small-claims-court

I flew with Finnair from Moscow to Montreal. My luggage got delayed by 3 days. As per Montreal Convention, I can spend up to 1,131 SDR on necessities as my luggage is missing and the airline is supposed to compensate me within 30 days. Finnair says that their policy states that they don't compensate me if I traveled to my home country - which is my case. Their policy goes against the Montreal Convention.

In case Finnair refuses to compensate me, what leverage do I have in this situation? It is usually advised to complain to CTA and then take the case to Small Claims Court. However I can't seem to find a Finnair representative in Canada. They do have any legal entity here, but no office.

```
Business Number (BN): 841340763
Registry ID: BC0770721
Registered Office Location: -
Status: Active
Status Notes: -
Business Type: BC Company
Created: 2006-10-03
```

What would be my options if they refuse to cover?

Note: I posted a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143219/can-i-sue-airline-that-does-not-have-a-representative-in-your-country?noredirect=1#comment355641_143219) in travel community, but was redirected here.

Comment: In New York, a foreign legal entity without a registered office will normally have a registered "agent for service of process" whose role it is to accept legal notices related to court actions.  Presumably something similar exists in British Columbia (assuming "BC" means "British Columbia") or wherever else in Canada the company does business.